# find problem in bash script

Tags: shell-script

I am writing a program printing the file and directory of a specify directory. But I have to ignore certain kind of file. We store them in `.ignorefile`.

So, to get just the file that I want, I use find function. But, I have the same error every time: `No such file or directory`.

And, when I try on my terminal it works perfectly with the same arguments.

An example :

- In my ignore file I have: `*.txt, *.cpp`
- When I execute my `.sh` file I put two arguments: the ignore file and a directory.
- Then, when I scan all text in my file to construct the argument files then I call my `store()` function.

Here you can see my code:

```
    function store(){
      dir="$1" 
      find_arg="$2" # Dir ! -name '*.txt' ! -name '*.cpp' -print
      echo $find_arg
      cmd=`find "$find_arg"`
      echo $cmd
    }
```

Here the function which build find_args :

```
function backup()
{
  if [ $1="-i" ] && [ -f $2 ]
  then
    backignore=$2
    if [ $3="-d" ] && [ -d $4 ]
    then
      directory=$4
      find_arg=" $directory"
      while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
        find_arg+=" ! -name "
        find_arg+="'"
        find_arg+=$line
        find_arg+="'"
      done < "$backignore"
      find_arg+=" -print"
      store $directory "$find_arg"
    else
      echo "please entrer a right directory"
    fi
  else
    echo "Please enter a right ignore file"
  fi
}

backup $1 $2 $3 $4
```

I call "sh" file

```
./file.sh -i ignorefile -d Source
```

output:

```
Source ! -name '\*.cpp' ! -name '\*.txt' -print
Source/unix_backup/example_files/backignore   
Source/unix_backup/example_files/Documents/rep1/file3.txt
Source/unix_backup/example_files/Documents/rep1/file4.cpp   
Source/unix_backup/example_files/Documents/rep3 
Source/unix_backup/example_files/Documents/rep3/rep4 
Source/unix_backup/example_files/Documents/rep3/rep4/file7.txt    
Source/unix_backup/example_files/Documents/rep3/rep4/file8.cpp
```

Comment: $dir isn't being used in the find command.  try `find "$dir" $find_arg`.  don't use quotes around $find_arg because you want it to add multiple args to the command line, not just one quoted arg.

Comment: Yes actually i don't use $dir because the directory is already in $find_arg. So now it works but it doesn't exclude *.cpp or *.txt file.
I wrote `cmd=\`find $find_arg\` `

Comment: Can you show us the full output verbatim?

Comment: @l0b0: 
the output : 
_Source ! -name '*.cpp' ! -name '*.txt' -print
Source/unix_backup/example_files/backignore
Source/unix_backup/example_files/Documents/rep1/file3.txt
Source/unix_backup/example_files/Documents/rep1/file4.cpp
Source/unix_backup/example_files/Documents/rep3
Source/unix_backup/example_files/Documents/rep3/rep4
Source/unix_backup/example_files/Documents/rep3/rep4/file7.txt
Source/unix_backup/example_files/Documents/rep3/rep4/file8.cpp_

Comment: @Alexis Please include the output in your question rather than a comment. It's not readable like this.

Comment: @l0b0 Oh yes sorry, it's done & I had some code to understand better what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

**`find_arg` is passed as a single argument** (because of the double quotes), which means **`find` is trying to find *all* files in a directory called `Dir ! -name '*.txt' ! -name '*.cpp' -print`** (Yes, that's a valid directory name). Try `printf '%q\n' "$find_arg"` to see the actual arguments as passed to `find`. Also, if your shell supports arrays, you should probably [use them to store arguments](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050#I.27m_constructing_a_command_based_on_information_that_is_only_known_at_run_time). And [Use More Quotes™](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)! And don't use `eval` here - `find` will print the file names just fine.

Answer (score 1):

1. You say that your .ignorefile has`*.txt, *.cpp` but from the output shown, it looks like it has `\*.txt, \*.cpp`.  Escaping the `*` is the source of your problem, it tells `find` to exclude files with a literal asterisk, rather than use it as a glob wildcard.  So, don't do that.
2. This version of your script fixes a few flaws and simplifies it a bit.  Amongst other things, it separates the arg processing (and uses getopts, which is built-in to sh) from the main logic of the `backup()` function.

```sh
function store() {
    echo find "$@"
    find "$@"
}   

function backup() {
  directory="$1"
  backignore="$2"

  # skip comments and blank lines
  sed -e 's/#.*// ; /^[[:space:]]*$/d' "$backignore" |
      while IFS= read -r line ; do
          find_arg+=" ! -name '$line'"
      done 
  find_arg+=" -print"
  store "$directory" $find_arg
} 

usage() { 
    echo "$(basename $0) [ -d directory ] [ -i ignorefile ]"
    exit 1
}   

directory=''
backignore='.ignorefile'    # default

while getopts "i:d:h" opt ; do
  case "$opt" in
    d)  directory="$OPTARG" ;;
    i)  backignore="$OPTARG" ;;
    *) usage ;;
  esac 
done

[ -z "$directory" ] && echo "Please provide a directory." && usage

backup "$directory" "$backignore"
```